# Compare array value with string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, compare

```
var string1 = "Hello, World";
var arr = string1.split(",");
var string2 = "Hello World";
```

How do I compare the value of the `arr` array with the value of the variable `string2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `join` method as below:

```js
var string1 = "Hello, World";
var arr = string1.split(",");
var string2 = "Hello World";
var arr_string = arr.join('');
console.log(arr_string == string2);
```

Or you could try `replace` as below:

```js
var string1 = "Hello, World";
var string2 = "Hello World";
var new_string1 = string1.replace(/,/g, '');
console.log(new_string1 == string2);
```